How to show only first line?
I am having trouble with this problem for a long time now. My problem is that I cannot figure out, how to save all the data from the Input Field to localstorage yet only show the first line in the list.
const ProgButton = document.getElementById("ProgButton")
const InputFieldProg = document.getElementById("InputFieldProg")
const ItemListProg = document.getElementById("ItemListProg")


const Main = document.getElementById("main")

LoadProgTasks()

function AddProgTask() {
    const ProgTask = InputFieldProg.value
    

    if (ProgTask) {
        CreateProgTaskElement(ProgTask)

        InputFieldProg.value = ''

        SaveProgTasks()
    }

}

ProgButton.addEventListener("click", AddProgTask)

function CreateProgTaskElement(ProgTask) {

    const ProgListItem = document.createElement("li")

    const firstLine = ProgTask.split('\n')[0];
    const taskContent = document.createElement('div')
    taskContent.innerHTML = firstLine.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')


    const DeleteProgButton = document.createElement('button')
    DeleteProgButton.textContent = "Megtekint"
    DeleteProgButton.className = "DeleteProgBut"

    DeleteProgButton.dataset.fullText = ProgTask;

    ProgListItem.appendChild(taskContent)
    ProgListItem.appendChild(DeleteProgButton)

    DeleteProgButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        Main.innerHTML = DeleteProgButton.dataset.fullText.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
        SaveProgTasks()
    })

    ItemListProg.appendChild(ProgListItem)
}

function SaveProgTasks() {
    let ProgTasks = []

    ItemListProg.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(function(item){
        ProgTasks.push(item.querySelector('div').innerHTML.replace('Megtekint', ''))
    })

    localStorage.setItem('ProgTask', JSON.stringify(ProgTasks))
}

function LoadProgTasks() {

    const ProgTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ProgTask') || '[]')

    ProgTasks.forEach(function(ProgTask) {
        CreateProgTaskElement(ProgTask)
})}

Please ignore that it is called Delete Button. it should be View Button but I havent changed it yet.
Here is the relevant HTML:
<aside id="bal"><div class="title">Prog</div>
        <ul id="ItemListProg"></ul>
        </aside>
        <div id="main">Main Content</div>
<div class="cont"><textarea id="InputFieldProg" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Írj ide..."></textarea>

        <button class="add" id="ProgButton">Hozzá adás</button></div>

What I want to ultimately achieve is lets say I write in the text area:
Javascript 2.
Make me a meal.
Now.
Only the Javascript 2. will be shown in the list but when I click on the button next to the list item in the main content I will see the whole thing that I wrote earlier not just the Javascript 2.

What about using CSS to hide the entire list, then show the first item?

You need to ensure that the full text is properly saved and retrieved from localStorage. Additionally, you need to correctly handle the content to make sure only the first line is shown in the list, and the full content is available for display.
const ProgButton = document.getElementById("ProgButton");
const InputFieldProg = document.getElementById("InputFieldProg");
const ItemListProg = document.getElementById("ItemListProg");
const Main = document.getElementById("main");

// Load tasks from localStorage when the page loads
LoadProgTasks();

function AddProgTask() {
    const ProgTask = InputFieldProg.value;

    if (ProgTask) {
        CreateProgTaskElement(ProgTask);

        // Clear the input field after adding the task
        InputFieldProg.value = '';

        // Save tasks to localStorage
        SaveProgTasks();
    }
}

ProgButton.addEventListener("click", AddProgTask);

function CreateProgTaskElement(ProgTask) {
    // Create the list item element
    const ProgListItem = document.createElement("li");

    // Get the first line of the task
    const firstLine = ProgTask.split('\n')[0];
    const taskContent = document.createElement('div');
    taskContent.innerHTML = firstLine.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

    // Create the view button
    const ViewProgButton = document.createElement('button');
    ViewProgButton.textContent = "View";
    ViewProgButton.className = "ViewProgBut";

    // Store the full text in a data attribute
    ViewProgButton.dataset.fullText = ProgTask;

    // Append content and button to the list item
    ProgListItem.appendChild(taskContent);
    ProgListItem.appendChild(ViewProgButton);

    // Add event listener for the view button
    ViewProgButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        Main.innerHTML = ViewProgButton.dataset.fullText.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    });

    // Append the list item to the list
    ItemListProg.appendChild(ProgListItem);
}

function SaveProgTasks() {
    let ProgTasks = [];

    // Collect all tasks from the list
    ItemListProg.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(function(item){
        ProgTasks.push(item.querySelector('button').dataset.fullText);
    });

    // Save tasks to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('ProgTask', JSON.stringify(ProgTasks));
}

function LoadProgTasks() {
    // Load tasks from localStorage
    const ProgTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ProgTask') || '[]');

    // Create list items for each task
    ProgTasks.forEach(function(ProgTask) {
        CreateProgTaskElement(ProgTask);
    });
}

